# WSL Ubuntu Remote Desktop,xrdp Error with quitting after reboot pc

Tags: screen

I am a rather new user of Ubuntu, and I'm trying to set up remote desktop access to my Ubuntu 22.04 by Powershell pc wsl. I have tried both native GNOME Remote Desktop and XRDP; however, I have not been able to reach the desired behaviour which is the following. When I

```
[Window Title]

Remote Desktop Connection

[Content]
Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:

1) Remote access to the server is not enabled
2) The remote computer is turned off
3) The remote computer is not available on the network

Make sure the remote computer is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled.

[^] Hide details  [OK]

[Expanded Information]
Error code: 0x204
Extended error code: 0x0
Timestamp (UTC): 11/01/23 07:11:15 AM

Press Ctrl+C to copy.
```

[image]

Comment: WSL is out of the box a command-line only installation of Ubuntu, no graphical desktop is installed.
Except this, please edit your question and explain clear from where / which machine you would like to access Ubuntu running in WSL.

Comment: I have intalled Ubuntu-desktop-installer, I am using pc with system  Windows 11 Pro. I can use --gui to run octave and  gimp ,,, I followed the instruction on web to install the remote desktop server many times.;nevertheless  the remote desktop still show black screen (sometimes blue when it show fail to connect server)